# How to check mostly used values of a field in a related list

Tags: trigger, process-builder

There are two objects account and contact. There is a picklist field on contact called **service** and a field on account called **prefered service**.

there can be n no of contacts for an account.

My requirement is

i have 5 contact records C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 under an account A1.

- C1- is having service as plumber
- C2- is having service as carpenter
- C3- is having service as plumber
- C4- is having service as gardenner
- C5- is having service as plumber

once inserted prefered service field of account should get updated with mostly used values as "Plumber"

How can i achieve that?

Regards

Comment: `before insert, before update` trigger ON Contact then get contact account then with this account id get all contact's `COUNT(service), service` limit 1; and update account record with the service;

Comment: In this how to get how many times a picklist value is used and update the value with highest no of time.

Comment: what you want is an aggregate query that can order by count(id) within each group but this isn't possible. Your trigger will need to `select count(id), accountId, service__c from Contact where accountId IN :setofAccountIds group by (accountId, service__c)` and then you'll use apex to find the max count for each accountId across its services.  Try writing the trigger (use an after trigger) and [edit] your post when(if) you get stuck